# Tense agreement in a particular situation

Tags: tense-agreement

Regarding the sentence marked in yellow, I am especially unsure about "was" or "is". Which one should I use if both the 1880 and 1852 articles still exist today?

> In the same 1880 text, the author mentions that his 1852 article **was/is** the first detailed account of what he calls the greatest scientific experiment of the century.

Can I use the combination "had been and still was". Does it sound well in English?

> In 1880, he was perfectly aware that the credibility of his 1852 account **had been and still was** quite low.

Answer (score 1):

In your first sentence

> the author mentions that his 1852 article **is**/**was** the first detailed account

Whether to use "is" or "was" depends on what you are trying to say.  If you use the present tense "is" it would mean you want to emphasize that it is still true today.  If you use the past "was" you would be emphasizing its importance in the past.

> the credibility of his 1852 account had been and still was quite low.

without further context you might want to use "had been and still is", otherwise you might add

> the credibility of his 1852 account had been and still was quite low until the 1860's.

meaning the credibility was low in 1852 until 1860.

Comment: The context of the second sentence is given by the first. In the 1880 article the author was aware that in 1852, when he wrote the first article, people did not believe him and in 1880, when he wrote the second text, the situation was unchanged. People still did not believe him.